Why is fieldDefinition not recognized as FilterOperationFieldDefinition in my custom HotChocolate filter handler?
I'm working on implementing a custom filter handler in HotChocolate for my GraphQL API. I have a filter input type RadiusFilterInput that contains fields Zip and Radius. I want to implement a custom filter operation Within to filter addresses within a certain radius.
public class RadiusFilterInput
{
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public int Radius { get; set; }
}

public static class RadiusFilterOperations
{
    public const int Within = 2048; // Define your operation constants
}

public class RadiusFilterInputType : FilterInputType<RadiusFilterInput>
{
    protected override void Configure(IFilterInputTypeDescriptor<RadiusFilterInput> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.BindFieldsExplicitly();

        descriptor.Field(x => x.Zip).Description("Zipcode");
        descriptor.Field(x => x.Radius).Description("Radius");

        descriptor.Operation(RadiusFilterOperations.Within)
                  .Name("within")
                  .Type<RadiusWithinOperationFilterInputType>();
    }
}

public class RadiusWithinOperationFilterInputType : FilterInputType
{
    protected override void Configure(IFilterInputTypeDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Operation(RadiusFilterOperations.Within)
                  .Name("within")
                  .Type<RadiusFilterInputType>();
        descriptor.AllowAnd(false).AllowOr(false);
    }
}

public class RadiusFilterHandler : FilterFieldHandler<QueryableFilterContext, Expression>
{
    protected int Operation = RadiusFilterOperations.Within;

    public override bool CanHandle(ITypeCompletionContext context, IFilterInputTypeDefinition typeDefinition, IFilterFieldDefinition fieldDefinition)
    {
        return context.Type is RadiusFilterInput &&
               fieldDefinition is FilterOperationFieldDefinition operationField &&
               operationField.Id == Operation;
    }

    // Implement the logic for handling the filtering operation
}

However, the fieldDefinition is FilterOperationFieldDefinition check in my RadiusFilterHandler's CanHandle method always returns false. As a result, my handler is not able to process the custom filter operation. I have verified that RadiusFilterOperations.Within is correctly defined and used consistently.
Here are the issues I'm encountering:
The fieldDefinition check fails, so the handler cannot recognize the custom operation.
Can anyone help me understand why the fieldDefinition check is failing and how to fix it? Are there any additional configurations or steps needed to correctly recognize FilterOperationFieldDefinition in the custom filter handler?
Thanks in advance!
